# Get directory path made by 'os.makedirs' as variable

Tags: python-2.7

Python2.7

filenamepath is a variable I created which is the file path of a Quicktime mov. Here I am checking if a folder with the filename of the Quicktime mov (but with .folder at end of foldername) exists and if not, os.makedirs is creating one.

How would I then assign this directory path to a variable? I want to then use shutil.move to move the .mov into the .folder.

```
import os

if not os.path.exists(filenamepath.replace(".mov", ".folder")):
    os.makedirs(filenamepath.replace(".mov", ".folder"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best best is probably to assign variables to target folder names:

```py
filenamepath = "/some/path/to/my_video.mov"
target_dir = filenamepath.replace(".mov", ".folder")

if not os.path.exists(target_dir):
    os.makedirs(target_dir)

shutil.move(filenamepath, target_dir)
```

That would clarify the intention of the code significantly.

Comment: Thanks a lot that instantly unconfused me

Comment: If the answer was satisfactory, please mark the answer as accepted! Glad to have helped out.